# Pandas create columns and update with values in apply

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

I'm trying to create new columns based on a column with dicts (as strings). 
As an example the columns contain {'human_number':100} and next {'robot_number': 3221}

Now what I want to do is go through each row and create a column based on the keys, and populate that value into the corresponding column.
for example:
if a row has {'human_number':100} in the type_info column, it should have a column called human_number with the number 100 inside, and nothing in robot_number.

```
def number_assign(row):
try:
    temp = next(iter(ast.literal_eval(row["type_info"])))
    row[temp] = next(iter(ast.literal_eval(row["type_info"]).values()))
except:
    pass
```

Which I then call with  df_test.apply(number_assign, axis=1)

`x = pd.DataFrame({'x': ["{'robot_number':1234}", "{'human_number':33}", '', "{'animal_number':223}"], 'y': [3, 4, 5,11]})`

Should become something like this:

`x = pd.DataFrame({'x': ["{'robot_number':1234}", "{'human_number':33}", '', "{'animal_number':223}"], 'y': [3, 4, 5,11], 'robot_number': [1234,'','',''], 'human_number' :['',33,'',''], 'animal_number':['','','',223] })`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Feed list of dictionaries to `pd.DataFrame`

The [`pd.DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.21/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html) constructor is versatile and efficient. You can feed a list of dictionaries directly:

```
from ast import literal_eval

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ["{'human_number':100}", "{'robot_number': 3221}"]})

df = pd.DataFrame(list(map(literal_eval, df['A'])))

print(df)

   human_number  robot_number
0         100.0           NaN
1           NaN        3221.0
```

The solution will work for arbitrary keys/values in each stringified dictionary. If you have empty strings, you can use a list comprehension with a ternary statement:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ["{'human_number':100}", "{'robot_number': 3221}", ""]})

df = pd.DataFrame([literal_eval(x) if x and (x == x) else {} for x in df['A']])

print(df)

   human_number  robot_number
0         100.0           NaN
1           NaN        3221.0
2           NaN           NaN
```

Comment: Thanks @jpp I've updated my post. Not all values are filled and I've provided an example.

Comment: @Mannemarak, See update, same principle applies, just use a list comprehension instead.

Comment: ValueError: malformed node or string: nan
My column has NaN, {} and actual values inside.
Would it be easier to just replace all NaN and {} before?

Comment: @Mannemarak, See update. You can use the fact `NaN != NaN`. No, it's not easier to just "replace all `NaN`" because Pandas is relatively inefficient with `object` dtype series.

Comment: Thanks for that @jpp! This creates a new dataframe though. I need to add these columns to the existing one I have. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: @Mannemarak, Use `df = df.join(df_append)` where `df_append` is the new dataframe and `df` is the existing one.

Comment: Great! Everything is as needed now.